# Grabbing image.svg from local server into Canvas

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, svg

I uploaded img.svg file to server using PHP uploading on local server that('C:/xampp/htdocs/finalproject/uploads/'), now I would like to get data from this server using javascript into Canvas. How can I fetch img.svg from server to img.src = ''; to display in my canvas.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

 var image = new Image();
 image.src = '';
 ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Is the upload path of the svg public accessable? If not you need to move the svg image to a location where the js in the browser can reach it. This public url is the one you need to use in `image.src`

Comment: And you will need to wait for <img>'s `onload` event.

Comment: I am new to PHP and js so I do not understand, I have an upload.php file to which I uploaded img.svg file and its saved in my local directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\finalproject\uploads\img.svg" I would like to get that file into my canvas (img.src = 'url';). Sorry for bad English.